# Adding user permission to MSSQL 2008 R2 DB

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions, addition

I have two DB (`PASDB` & `safenet`) in which I want to add the user `rhaengine`.

I managed to add the user for `safenet` DB, however when I tried to add for `PASDB`, it prompt me the error

> "The login already has an account under a different user name".

I assume it is saying that the user already exist. In that case how to I add an existing user?

(I can't add image cuz need rep points >< )

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Zlcm

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Zlc7

Comment: refer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35225/the-login-already-has-an-account-under-a-different-user-name

Comment: Ah i see, there was another user using the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS goto Logins, right click on `rhaengine` login, select properties. Login properties dialog is shown. Click on `User Mappings` located on the left pane. Select the desired database(s) and assign database roles.